# Google Maps API v3: Smooth zoom on Ground Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a static image, which I wanna be able to zoom into with the Google Maps API. However, I do not have any higher resolution tiles available, so the idea was to simply zoom in the one image and stretch it accordingly. This works fine if I make the `getTileURL()` function `return null`, and instead define the image as a GroundOverlay. The problem is, zooming in on images for GroundOverlays has to resize and reposition them, and you can notice that process distinctly. This is an example from the Google Maps Developer's Guide, which has the same problem:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

If you zoom in on the map, you will notice the image appearing again in regular size for a split second, then be stretched and repositioned to fit the coordinates.

Is there a way to disable that entirely? I know it can zoom into images smoothly, because it does that with regular image tiles, it zooms in and the replaces them as soon as the higher resolution tiles have loaded. Is it possible to somehow emulate this effect for GroundOverlays?

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and I'm still somewhat interested in it. If you do find a solution I would appreciate it if you could post it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: don't know if this thread is still open, but I'm interested in making a subclass from having access to the onAdd() functions etc. of groundoverlay, as is possible with the OverlayView base class, if anyone knows how? I say this, because the coordinate projection of OverlayViews and groundoverlays differ. Custom overlay images will thus sometimes have an coordinate offset whereas groundoverlays place it correctly, but has awful "zoom smooth" as mentioned by Stjepan