# Overlay positioning offset - Overlay view vs. ground overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am struggling with the positioning of image overlays (projection) on the map, and both implementations have shortcomings nl.:

- Custom Overlay views (as implemented @ [Maps API overlay example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)) gives me the capability of customizing the "onAdd()" functions etc., but has an projection offset when drawing on the map as such:
  [image: image over SA]
- Ground overlays (as implemented @ [Maps API ground overlay example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple)) displays the positioning projection correct, but has the "refresh and positioning" problem (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321832/google-maps-api-v3-smooth-zoom-on-ground-overlay)) that is VERY annoying and looks unprofessional. This is how the thing looks while I zoom in/out and the overlay refreshes (If I quickly take a printscreen):
  [image: glitch while refresh]
- I've also tried adding custom overlay views and just getting and using the projection ("getProjection()") of ground overlay, but no success so far. Here is my code snippet:

  ```
  //constructor of image overlay class
  function ImageOverlay(bounds,image,map)
  {   
    // Now initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = null;
    this.setMap(map);

    //make object of ground overlay to get projection later
    this.groundOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(image,bounds);
  }

  //SOME OTHER CODE, NOT IMPORTANT

  //redraw the image every time zoom level is changed
  ImageOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

    if(this.div_ != null)
    {
      //======
      //normally this is used for overlay views
      //======
      //
      //get boundary corners - the Mercator projection
      /*var overlayProjection = this.getProjection(); //use projection of image overlay view
      var sw =  overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

      // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';*/

      //this is what I try
      var GOProjection = this.groundOverlay.getProjection(); 
      var GOsw = GOProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var GOne = GOProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = GOsw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = GOne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (GOne.x - GOsw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (GOsw.y - GOne.y) + 'px';
    }

  };
  ```

I would very much appreciate some help with this please?

Comment: It can be difficult to align an image exactly on a map, precisely because of the longitude stretching and the fact that the coordinates are hard to get right exactly.

Comment: It could be a solution to break up the image exactly at lat/lng lines (34,78 as a random example). This would solve alignment problems, but would be difficult to implement.

Comment: hi bcdan, thanks for the reply.but that is definitively not the case.My border coordinates are provided by a geographical broadcasting coverage prediction tool.My coordinates are to a 6th decimal (en decimal degrees), whereas the offset is roughly 0.2 decimal degrees. Also, that is why I stated in my question that the overlay is positioned correctly when loading via "groundoverlays",while positioned with an offset when loading via "overlay views". It must be that they use different projections...I just don't want to use the conventional ground overlay method because of the sh!tty refresh thing